# Why is an array of a value classes compiled to an array of objects?

Tags: scala

As I understand, if you create an array of a value class, you're actually creating an array of objects rather than the wrapped primitive. What's the reason behind this?

source:

```
class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal

class Main {
  val i: Int = 1
  val w: Wrapper = new Wrapper(1)
  val wrappers = Array[Wrapper](new Wrapper(1), new Wrapper(2))
  val ints = Array[Int](1, 2)
}
```

javap output:

```
public class Main {
  public int i();
  public int w();
  public Wrapper[] wrappers(); // <----why can't this be int[] as well
  public int[] ints();
  public Main();
}
```

Comment: **value classes** are actually very fragile and not that recommended IMHO. I would just use them for extension methods and other forms of just one time wrapping. But not as opaque types _(which will come in Scala 3)_ if you need that functionality in Scala 2.the best would be to use a tagged type, my personal recommendation would be [**newtype**](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype).

Comment: Shapeless is pretty popular to tag a type. It will compile to primitive array when you have an array of tagged primitives

Comment: Cool thanks for alerting me to this! I'll need to do more reading but looks like tagged types are what I thought value classes were going to be. I'll need to read more about opaque types too, this seems like a really good article although I'm not done with understanding it: https://medium.com/iterators/to-tag-a-type-88dc344bb66c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the constraints of value classes is that `x.isInstanceOf[ValueClass]` should still work correctly. Where correctly means: transparently, without the programmer having to be aware when values may or may not be boxed.

If an `Array[Meter]` would be represented as an `Array[Int]` at runtime the following code would not work as expected, because the information that the ints in the array are actually meters is lost.

```
class Meter(val value: Int) extends AnyVal

def centimeters[A](as: Array[A]) = as.collect{ case m: Meter => m.value * 100 }
```

Note that if you have `val m = new Meter(42); m.isInstanceOf[Meter]` then the compiler knows that `m` is a `Meter` even though it's an `Int` at runtime and he can inline the `isInstanceOf` call to `true`.

Also note that this wouldn't work for arrays. If you would box the values in the array on demand you'd have to create a new array, which wouldn't be transparent to the programmer because arrays are mutable and use reference equality. It would also be a disaster for performance with large arrays.

Comment: I think, your last sentence explains exactly why the previous text doesn't actually make sense :) If the compiler _knows_ that `as` holds meters, then the code in your example should work, regardless of how the array is actually represented at the byte code level. I don't think there is actually a solid reason to compile it into an an array of objects, it _could_ be made to work with primitives, it's just would be more complex, and thus was decided against.

Comment: No. The compiler does _not_ know that `as` only contains `Meter` instances. I can also pass a `Array[Int]` or `Array[String]` or `Array[Any]` to `centimeters`. The compiler knows that `m` contains a `Meter` because it is typed as `Meter`. If I manually type it as `Any`, or `Length` (where `Meter` extends `Length`), then `42` will be boxed in a `Meter` object.

Comment: Well, what about `def foo[A](x: A) = x match { case m: Meter => m.value*100; case _ => 0  }`? Same thing, right? So, the problem is not specific to arrays then. By your logic, value classes would always end up being instantiated. That is not the case though.

Comment: If you call `foo(someMeter)` then `someMeter` will get boxed. Once you upcast a value class or put it in some generic context it will get instantiated. If you call a method of a superclass that doesn't get overriden in the value class, that value class will get instantiated.

Comment: Exactly. Same thing _could_ happen with arrays, it just doesn't because it would complicate things, not because it is impossible. It was just decided to box it every time, because it is simpler.

Comment: So I follow your description of the pattern matching part - your code needs to distinguish at runtime between Int and Meter. However, I didn't follow the part about the array, specifically the sentence fragment "If you would box the values in the array on demand you'd have to create a new array".

Comment: If you would have an `Array[Int]` at runtime and you need to box all ints to Meter objects, you would have to create an `Array[Meter]` to store them in. I guess theoretically the compiler could do some kind of escape analysis and create an `Array[Int]` if the array never escapes the local scope and isn't upcast or anything, and an `Array[Meter]` otherwise instead of boxing on demand. But that would probably be a lot of extra complication for a rare use case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I still don't follow. Wouldn't you know at compile time if you have an Array[Int] and want to create an Array[Meter]?

Comment: Yes you would. I think it would definitely be possible to do it. But it would differ from the strategy that is implemented now. Now `val m: Meter = new Meter(42)` will _always_ result in a variable of type `int` at runtime regardless of whether it needs to get boxed later or not. I don't know how much harder that would be.

Comment: And like I said I'm not sure how useful it would be either. Because of things like separate compilation and because methods and classes are not specialized by default (which would create an insane amount of extra bytecode) only local or private variables which don't escape their local or private scope could be optimized. The Scala compiler can't really do whole-program optimizations on the bytecode because of how the JVM platform works.

Comment: Thanks for continuing the thread. if I understand you correctly, because in Java you can compile file1 separately from file2 based on the interface, you wouldn't be able to optimize to an int[] in file1 because you might need the runtime type in file2. Unless you insert the boxing and unboxing code everywhere that's needed.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html:

> **Allocation Summary**
>
> A value class is actually instantiated when:
>
> 1. a value class is treated as another type.
> 2. **a value class is assigned to an array.**
> 3. doing runtime type tests, such as pattern matching.

[...]

> Another situation where an allocation is necessary is when assigning
>   to an array, even if it is an array of that value class. For example,

```
val m = Meter(5.0)
val array = Array[Meter](m)
```

> The array here contains actual Meter instances and not just the underlying double primitives.

This has probably something to do with type erasure, or simply because you're creating an array of a specific type, which doesn't allow one type to be treated as another. In any case, it's a technical limitation.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking more to understand the underlying reason for this technical limitation / design decision.

Comment: @allstar Good luck, but be warned that's going to be a deep dive into scalac internals.

Comment: Here, this might help you: [Code handling value classes in the Scala compiler from Feb 7 2012](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5f02cf9f4035a90225e77a978354ee7c0504e601/src/compiler/scala/reflect/internal/Definitions.scala) and [the same file in the current state](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Definitions.scala)